# Airflow 2.0.2 - Jinja2 top-level template error

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, airflow

I'm seeing the below error happen:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> line 1138, in _run_raw_task
> self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> line 1275, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
> self.render_templates(context=context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> line 1779, in render_templates
> self.task.render_template_fields(context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py",
> line 892, in render_template_fields
> self._do_render_template_fields(self, self.template_fields, context, jinja_env, set())   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py",
> line 905, in _do_render_template_fields
> rendered_content = self.render_template(content, context, jinja_env, seen_oids)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py",
> line 942, in render_template
> return jinja_env.from_string(content).render(**context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line
> 1090, in render
> self.environment.handle_exception()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line
> 832, in handle_exception
> reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28,
> in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>
> File "", line 1, in top-level template code
> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError:
> 'target_table' is undefined

when trying to run this task in Airflow:

```
TABLE_NAME = 'sales.il_sales'

t4 = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='my_test_query.sql',
    sql='sql/my_test_query.sql',
    params={
        'target_table': TABLE_NAME,
    },
    retries=0,
    pool='airflow')
```

this is strange because target_table is `'sales.il_sales'`

Comment: You need to post the SQL code

Comment: @Elad I thought the error was occurring in the params, because that's where we have 'target_table'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sql/my_test_query.sql` file if you are using `{{ target_table }}` it won't work. You need to use `{{ params.target_table }}`.

Example:

```sql
SELECT * from {{ params.target_table }}
```

Check the example in docs here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja

Comment: thanks for responding! this would work, but lets say I have a custom operator, how would I get this to work, for example I've tried to add the below to template_fields/template_ext and I'm still seeing the same error:

class SnowflakeTestOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ['sql', 'params', 'target_table']
    template_ext = ['.sql', '.target_table']

Comment: It will work the same. params is parameter of BaseOperator

Comment: @Elad thank you for answering! is there a way I wouldn't have to add params.target_table to the queries, I have a lot of queries to change so I'm just curious. I've tried by adding it to the template_fields = ['sql', 'params'] but that didn't work

Comment: that won't work. You can create user defined macro but you will still need to edit the template in the sql files. not really sure what is the problem with that? You can do that in single button click in most IDEs.