# How to pass a parameter to complete my sql query when running a task in Airflow with snowflake?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to generate a SQL in which a value is passed as a parameter, like a table name.
I am writing a Snowflake operator and in the operator I am trying to pass a parameter.
I have two problems with it.

Q1. One is, I don’t know exactly how to pass the parameter.

Q2. The other is, the parameter is made from a task, say A, and it can be stored at XCom but I don’t know how to get the value stored at XCom within the operator. It does not have to be in XCom. I just want to generate the value from a task (i.e., python function) and pass that value to the following task operator.

Here is the snippet.
Suppose I have two files. One is the python file including the dag. The other is sql.

In my simplified python file:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.models.xcom import XCom


DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email": ["airflow@example.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="test_my_dag",
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="@once",
)


def set_my_table(ti):
    ti.xcom_push(key="set_my_table", value="my_unique_table")
    return

set_my_table = PythonOperator(
    task_id="set_my_table",
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=set_my_table,
)

select_example = SnowflakeOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="select_example",
    snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn",    
    sql='sql/test.sql',
    params={"table_name": "{{ti.xcom_pull(my_table)}}"},   <- this wouldn't work, as i get an error of not finding the task instance, ti.
)


set_my_table >> select_example
```

inside test.sql:

```sql
USE WAREHOUSE some_ware_house;

SELECT * from {{my_table}} LIMIT 100;
```

My environment:

- Python 3.7
- apache-airflow==2.2.2
- apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==2.3.0
- [aws-mwaa-local-runner](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner)

Up till now, at least I know the following.

- Airflow templating with Jinja could pass a parameter by `{{}}` notation, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67621367/airflow-2-0-2-jinja2-top-level-template-error).

If I run a code similar to the above, I get this error.

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork
    args.func(args, dag=self.dag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 292, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_raw_task(args, ti)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 184, in _run_raw_task
    error_file=args.error_file,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1332, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1458, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1514, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/snowflake/operators/snowflake.py", line 129, in execute
    execution_info = hook.run(self.sql, autocommit=self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/snowflake/hooks/snowflake.py", line 271, in run
    with self.get_conn() as conn:
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/snowflake/hooks/snowflake.py", line 223, in get_conn
    conn = connector.connect(**conn_config)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/__init__.py", line 51, in Connect
    return SnowflakeConnection(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 296, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 549, in connect
    self.__open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 788, in __open_connection
    self._authenticate(auth_instance)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 1051, in _authenticate
    self.__authenticate(self.__preprocess_auth_instance(auth_instance))
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 1083, in __authenticate
    session_parameters=self._session_parameters,
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth.py", line 262, in authenticate
    socket_timeout=auth_timeout,
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 713, in _post_request
    _include_retry_params=_include_retry_params,
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 795, in fetch
    session, method, full_url, headers, data, retry_ctx, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 917, in _request_exec_wrapper
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 844, in _request_exec_wrapper
    **kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 1116, in _request_exec
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 1026, in _request_exec
    auth=SnowflakeAuth(token),
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 499, in send
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connection.py", line 424, in connect
    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ssl_wrap_socket.py", line 78, in ssl_wrap_socket_with_ocsp
    from .ocsp_asn1crypto import SnowflakeOCSPAsn1Crypto as SFOCSP
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_asn1crypto.py", line 47, in <module>
    from snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake import SnowflakeOCSP
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_snowflake.py", line 72, in <module>
    from .cache import SFDictCache, SFDictFileCache
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cache.py", line 20, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import NamedTuple, Self
ImportError: cannot import name 'NamedTuple' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

I appreciate any of your input. Thank you.

Comment: I actually find an answer to my first question!

I was able to pass my value as params as follows:

```select_example = SnowflakeOperator(dag=dag, task_id="select_example", snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn", sql='sql/test.sql', params={"table_name": "my_unique_table"}, )```

Actually, this is related to the bug about [the version incompatibility of airflow and typing_extensions](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/1206). I needed to upgrade the typing_extensions to be more than 4.3.0.

I am still looking for an answer to Q2.